# como mostrar consultas de 2 tablas en una sola tabla con MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo estas tablas

Alumno

```
1. Id
2. Nombre
3. Apellido
4. documento      --es numerico
5. Id_escuela     --numerico pero enlaza a Escuela
```

Escuela

```
1. Id_escuela       ---enlace
2. Nombre_escuela
```

Aqui mi duda, quiero que en una sola tabla se pueda ver solamente estos datos

```
1. Nombre
2. Apellido
3. Nombre_escuela
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo?, soy nuevo en SQL y lo necesito para poder mostrarlo en un datagridview de visual basic, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una consulta simple haciendo uso de `JOIN` (inner join)

```
SELECT a.Nombre, a.Apellido, e.Nombre_escuela
FROM Alumno a
JOIN Escuela e on a.Id_escuela = e.Id_escuela
```

Comment: ohhhhhh, interesante, gracias **Diego Torres**

Comment: Un momento, no funciona, al parecer el error empieza en **FROM**

Comment: ¿Exactamente a que te refieres con "no funciona"? ¿Hay un mensaje de error? cópialo para saber cual es el problema.

Comment: Dice **Error de sintaxis en la clausula FROM**

Comment: acabo de editar, pero de la siguiente manera `SELECT Alumno.Nombre AS Alumno_Nombre, Alumno.Apellido, Alumno.Procedencia, Alumno.Id_escuela, Escuela.Nombre AS Escuela_Nombre
FROM Escuela INNER JOIN Alumno ON Escuela.[Id_escuela] = Alumno.[Id_escuela];`

Comment: Bueno es que estaba haciendo la consulta desde **ACCESS**, ¿como seria en sql o Mysql?, cómo se escribe en forma normal?

Comment: Creé un ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c011a/1/0) Puedes ver que aquí corre en MySql sin problema.

Comment: Si esta bien funciona, hay algo que me habia olvidado , habia creado una relacion de tabla Alumno a Escuela que es **Id_escuela**

Answer (score 2):

Con un `join` entre las dos tablas debería bastar de este modo

```
SELECT Alumno.Nombre, Alumno.Apellido, Escuela.Nombre_escuela
FROM Escuela
JOIN Alumno ON Escuela.Id_escuela = Alumno.Id_escuela;
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

El `Join` o `Inner Join` va a buscar las coincidencias que existan entre la tabla de la derecha con los registros de la tabla de la izquierda y los unirá en un resultado final; en este caso se hace el cruce por medio de la llave primaria en `Escuela` y la llave foránea en `Alumno`

Debes tener presente que el `Inner Join` solo mostrará los resultados de la izquierda que tenga un registro asociado con la tabla de la derecha; descartando aquellos que no cumplan esta coindición

También ten presente que usé la sintáxis de `NombreTabla.nombreColumna` para mandar llamar a cada valor requerido

Comment: ohhhhhh, interesante, gracias **shadow**

Comment: Un momento, no funciona, al parecer el error empieza en **FROM**

Comment: Bueno dice que el error empieza en **FROM**